# Flask app getting error of "could not locate flask application. .....FLASK_APP environment variable" for Flask Migrate

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, database-migration

I have a file `db_table.py` that looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:password@localhost/mydb'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
.....db tables....
```

When I try to run:

```
flask db init
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not locate Flask application. You did not provide the FLASK_APP environment variable.
```

I tried first manually setting `FLASK_APP` var, by doing `set FLASK_APP=app.py` then running `flask db init` again, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: if your application lives in `db_table.py` file then you should expert this file: `export FLASK_APP=db_table.py`

Comment: and test your env: `printenv FLASK_APP`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `flask` command line argument needs to know what module to locate the current `Flask` app instance in.

You can pass in the module name using the `--app` argument:

```
flask —-app db_table
```

See the [*Command Line Interface* documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/cli/):

> The `flask` command is installed by Flask, not your application; it must be told where to find your application in order to use it. The `--app` option is used to specify how to load the application.

Alternatively, you can set the environment variable `FLASK_APP`; the `flask` command will use its value if there is no `--app` command-line switch:

```
export FLASK_APP=db_table
```

Answer (score 11):

You can refer to [this documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/) to learn how to set environment variables in Flask.

Unix Bash (Linux, Mac, etc.):

```
$ export FLASK_APP=hello
$ flask run
```

Windows CMD:

```
> set FLASK_APP=hello
> flask run
```

Windows PowerShell:

```
> $env:FLASK_APP = "hello"
> flask run
```

Comment: Powershell solution worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Some problem will can happen if you use DispatcherMiddleware (werkzeug.wsgi).
Change return object from app_dispatch to app without app_dispatch for migrate time.

This is a rare case, I hope someone helps...

Answer (score 0):

For VSCODE Windows run I was trying below code step and it was workable for me:

```
set FLASK_APP=main.py
$env:FLASK_APP = "main.py"
flask run
```

or

```
set FLASK_APP=main.py
$env:FLASK_APP = "main.py"
flask db init
```

Answer (score -1):

In VS code editor, click on Run and Debug. Select Flask debugger and type your file name. This worked for me and hope it works for you too.

Answer (score -1):

I just spent 20 minutes researching this without any luck.

1. I'm using Windows PowerShell.
2. Use the below command:

```
$env:FLASK_APP = "XXXapplicationNameXXX"
```

3. Use the below command:

```
python -m flask run
```

I got the message:

```
"Serving Flask app 'appName'" "Running on http://127.0.0.1:500"
```

Best of luck...